# Accessing data of a field from custom widget

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In a custom widget, is the data of a field that we turned into widget available to be used inside the widget?

For example if I make a custom widget for a `one2many` field, when I display that field using XML like this

```
<field name="myfield" widget="mywidget"/>
```

Can we use the data of field `myfield`? In my case for iteration, for looping and making a custom widget for each items inside the field.

Is this possible?

I didn't see any example in the https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the data is inside

```
self.field_manager.datarecord
```

You can use `console.log` to shows its content. You can also use it for coding your JavaScript.